# SqlServer - cant re-create view after renaming table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to rename a table in SqlServer 2012.  This works fine (using sp_rename), but as many have pointed out, references to the table are not changed (although it seems like the FK references we updated, but NOT the FK names).

I therefore dropped all of the views that reference the table, and then attempted to re-create them using the new table name.  However, the view creation process fails because it thinks that the new table does not exist. WTF?

Refreshing the tables, views and database doesn't help.  How can the view creation process be refreshed with the latest set of table names after a rename operation?

Comment: Can you post a script that recreates the problem?

Comment: are you actually trying it, or just looking at the squiggly lines under the name? if the latter, refresh the local intellisense cache. if you actually try to run it if it truly has the right name, it will work regardless of what intellisense tells you.